# Complex graph in Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to imitate this graph, or get as close as feasible:

http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/1748/graphu.png

Features:

- Codes at the bottom (Need to have)
- Rate at the side (Need to have)
- Both this year's dataset and last year's dataset (Need to have)
- Up-bars and downbars to indicate improvement / deterioration (Nice to have)

I know how to create it in Excel:

- Create a line graph for the two datasets
- In the graph's properties, remove lines
- Insert then format the up bars and down bars as appropriate

I've managed to get this close in the Layout view of Reporting Services:
http://img686.imageshack.us/img686/5730/layoutt.png

It's a line graph with the trend lines disabled.  No up-bars / down-bars, but that's acceptable.

The problem is, when I switch to Preview / Publish view, this is what it becomes:
http://img37.imageshack.us/img37/6824/previewyb.png

The lines all appear for no apparent reason.

I posted an earlier (now deleted) question for advice on this, and received the suggestion of using a scatter graph.  But unless I'm missing something, the scatter graph requires two numeric axes?  When I try to drop the "Rate" value on the "Y value" field, I get the error "Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: value"  (There is no report parameter "Value".)  It also doesn't seem to be able to have two datasets on the one axis?

So, what should I be doing?  Is there some way to get the trendlines to go away in the preview / publish view?  Alternatively, is there some way to get scatter plots to do what I'm after?  Or some other graph that would do it simply?

EDIT: This is in Reporting Services 2005, so you know.

Comment: 2005.  Sorry, should have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDL below. I just use defaults of everything. For some reason I had to set the colours for the graph to show anything. And you have to fill the high and low as well. I just put in the average of the open and close so they did not show.

EDIT: Modified to include the crosses and diamonds. I set all the values of a new series to lastyear then turned on only the markers. Then I did the same again for the thisyear. They do not seem to be positioned ideally but that is the best I could do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <rd:DataSourceID>892866e1-c006-4497-9545-251d2a43feb0</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=rover4;Initial Catalog=master</ConnectString>
        <IntegratedSecurity>true</IntegratedSecurity>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <InteractiveHeight>29.7cm</InteractiveHeight>
  <rd:DrawGrid>true</rd:DrawGrid>
  <InteractiveWidth>21cm</InteractiveWidth>
  <rd:GridSpacing>0.25cm</rd:GridSpacing>
  <rd:SnapToGrid>true</rd:SnapToGrid>
  <RightMargin>2.5cm</RightMargin>
  <LeftMargin>2.5cm</LeftMargin>
  <BottomMargin>2.5cm</BottomMargin>
  <rd:ReportID>55a6b44d-b38d-4f58-b9bf-fd26c6f80e4a</rd:ReportID>
  <PageWidth>21cm</PageWidth>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="master">
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="codename">
          <DataField>codename</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="thisyear">
          <DataField>thisyear</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="lastyear">
          <DataField>lastyear</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>Select 'code1'  as codename, 45 as thisyear, 46 as lastyear
union
Select 'code2'  as codename, 42 as thisyear, 55 as lastyear
union
Select 'code3'  as codename, 57 as thisyear, 40 as lastyear
union
Select 'code4'  as codename, 10 as thisyear, 11 as lastyear</CommandText>
        <rd:UseGenericDesigner>true</rd:UseGenericDesigner>
      </Query>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <Width>16cm</Width>
  <Body>
    <ColumnSpacing>1cm</ColumnSpacing>
    <ReportItems>
      <Chart Name="chart1">
        <Legend>
          <Style>
            <BorderStyle>
              <Default>Solid</Default>
            </BorderStyle>
          </Style>
          <Position>RightCenter</Position>
        </Legend>
        <CategoryAxis>
          <Axis>
            <Title />
            <MajorGridLines>
              <Style>
                <BorderStyle>
                  <Default>Solid</Default>
                </BorderStyle>
              </Style>
            </MajorGridLines>
            <MinorGridLines>
              <Style>
                <BorderStyle>
                  <Default>Solid</Default>
                </BorderStyle>
              </Style>
            </MinorGridLines>
            <MajorTickMarks>Outside</MajorTickMarks>
            <Min>0</Min>
            <Visible>true</Visible>
          </Axis>
        </CategoryAxis>
        <DataSetName>master</DataSetName>
        <PlotArea>
          <Style>
            <BackgroundColor>LightGrey</BackgroundColor>
            <BorderStyle>
              <Default>Solid</Default>
            </BorderStyle>
          </Style>
        </PlotArea>
        <ThreeDProperties>
          <Rotation>30</Rotation>
          <Inclination>30</Inclination>
          <Shading>Simple</Shading>
          <WallThickness>50</WallThickness>
        </ThreeDProperties>
        <PointWidth>0</PointWidth>
        <SeriesGroupings>
          <SeriesGrouping>
            <StaticSeries>
              <StaticMember>
                <Label>Value2</Label>
              </StaticMember>
              <StaticMember>
                <Label>This year markers</Label>
              </StaticMember>
              <StaticMember>
                <Label>last year markers</Label>
              </StaticMember>
            </StaticSeries>
          </SeriesGrouping>
        </SeriesGroupings>
        <Top>0.25cm</Top>
        <Subtype>Candlestick</Subtype>
        <ValueAxis>
          <Axis>
            <Title />
            <MajorGridLines>
              <ShowGridLines>true</ShowGridLines>
              <Style>
                <BorderStyle>
                  <Default>Solid</Default>
                </BorderStyle>
              </Style>
            </MajorGridLines>
            <MinorGridLines>
              <Style>
                <BorderStyle>
                  <Default>Solid</Default>
                </BorderStyle>
              </Style>
            </MinorGridLines>
            <MajorTickMarks>Outside</MajorTickMarks>
            <Min>0</Min>
            <Max>100</Max>
            <Margin>true</Margin>
            <Visible>true</Visible>
            <Scalar>true</Scalar>
          </Axis>
        </ValueAxis>
        <Type>Stock</Type>
        <Width>15cm</Width>
        <CategoryGroupings>
          <CategoryGrouping>
            <DynamicCategories>
              <Grouping Name="chart1_CategoryGroup1">
                <GroupExpressions>
                  <GroupExpression>=Fields!codename.Value</GroupExpression>
                </GroupExpressions>
              </Grouping>
              <Label>=Fields!codename.Value</Label>
            </DynamicCategories>
          </CategoryGrouping>
        </CategoryGroupings>
        <Palette>Default</Palette>
        <ChartData>
          <ChartSeries>
            <DataPoints>
              <DataPoint>
                <DataValues>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=(Fields!thisyear.Value+Fields!lastyear.Value)/2</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=(Fields!thisyear.Value+Fields!lastyear.Value)/2</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!lastyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!thisyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                </DataValues>
                <DataLabel />
                <Style>
                  <BackgroundColor>SandyBrown</BackgroundColor>
                  <BackgroundGradientEndColor>Lime</BackgroundGradientEndColor>
                  <BorderColor>
                    <Default>Red</Default>
                  </BorderColor>
                </Style>
                <Marker>
                  <Size>6pt</Size>
                </Marker>
              </DataPoint>
            </DataPoints>
          </ChartSeries>
          <ChartSeries>
            <DataPoints>
              <DataPoint>
                <DataValues>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!thisyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!thisyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!thisyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!thisyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                </DataValues>
                <DataLabel />
                <Style />
                <Marker>
                  <Type>Diamond</Type>
                  <Size>6pt</Size>
                </Marker>
              </DataPoint>
            </DataPoints>
          </ChartSeries>
          <ChartSeries>
            <DataPoints>
              <DataPoint>
                <DataValues>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!lastyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!lastyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!lastyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                  <DataValue>
                    <Value>=Sum(Fields!lastyear.Value)</Value>
                  </DataValue>
                </DataValues>
                <DataLabel />
                <Style />
                <Marker>
                  <Type>Cross</Type>
                  <Size>6pt</Size>
                </Marker>
              </DataPoint>
            </DataPoints>
          </ChartSeries>
        </ChartData>
        <Style>
          <BackgroundColor>White</BackgroundColor>
        </Style>
        <Title />
        <Left>0.5cm</Left>
      </Chart>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>10.36905cm</Height>
  </Body>
  <Language>en-US</Language>
  <TopMargin>2.5cm</TopMargin>
  <PageHeight>29.7cm</PageHeight>
</Report>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way to include the Xs and Os or something to point out this year vs last year?  I played around with the settings, and didn't see anything obvious...